# Perl regular expression substitution changes only first letter of each line

Tags: regex, perl, notepad++

I am having trouble doing the simplest of Perl REGEX. It is working correctly in Notepad++ but not Perl.

```
open FILE, "Something.txt";
while (<FILE>) {
   s/./f/;
    print;
}
```

However the output only changes the first letter of each line to F. When this regular expression is clearly saying change every character to F!

Answer (score 3):

i haven't used perl in a while, but try `s/./f/g` (the g makes it global, rather than stopping after the first match, according to Quentin in comments (thanks)).

Comment: Start of line would be `s/^./g/`. Global means it doesn't stop after the first match.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `g` modifier to make it global, otherwise it will stop after the first match.

```
s/./f/g
```

Comment: Is there a reason for the trailing slash?

Answer (score 1):

See the following sample code :

The fle :

```
$ cat /tmp/test
aaaa
bbbb
cccc
```

The Perl code (I use `perlconsole`)

```
Perl> open FH, "<", "/tmp/test"
1

Perl> while (<FH>) { s/./f/g; print; }
ffff
ffff
ffff


Perl> close FH
1

Perl>
```

The **g** modifier in the substitution means all occurrences, see http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers

Comment: Mhhhhh ? What's going on (why down voted ?) ? Have you tested this code ? :/

Comment: You appear to have, with more code but less clarity, repeated the question … without actually answering it.

Comment: After the edit, the sample output doesn't match what I'd expect the (edited) code to output, or what the asker was looking for. It also falls into the category of a "spot-the-difference solution" that fails to highlight what has changed or explain why.

Comment: Edited again to explain what's changed. =)

Answer (score 0):

You need to flag it for global change:

```
open FILE, "Something.txt";
while (<FILE>) {
   s/./f/g;
    print;
}
CLOSE (FILE);
```